# How to convert MVC model to DATASET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, casting

I am trying to convert one of the models of my project to dataset. Before sent dt to return, I need to cast it to Person otherwise it produces meaningless output.

But I am not sure do I firstly cast to my model (Person - each properties) before return or do I need to cast datatable dt to my model?

```
 public ActionResult Index() {

            DataModel dt = new DataModel();



            using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
                sqlcon.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Person", sqlcon);
                sqlDa.Fill(dt);
            }

            return View(dt);
        }
```

Index view:

```
@model System.Data.DataTable

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
    </tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td> @Model.Rows [i][1] </td>
            <td> @Model.Rows [i][2] </td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
<hr>
<a href="@Url.Action("Create","Renter")">Add Person</a>
```

Can anyone help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Convert dataset to MVC model?

Comment: @HienNguyen How can I do that operation?

Comment: your title is convert model to dataset, i want to confirm what you want?

Comment: @HienNguyen I am not sure about it but I guess I need to convert my model to dataTable before I return to view.

Comment: In your MVC you should not return Dataset/DataTable to view

Comment: @HienNguyen   When I use the above cod piece, I am getting "System.Data.DataRowCollection [i][1]"  output in the columns instead of person`s name and surname. So I guessed It can be cast problem between them.

Comment: also post your view to question

Comment: @HienNguyen posted it.

Comment: what class DataModel  contains?

Comment: @HienNguyen Should It contain a class? I did not generated any class in terms of data model, I have just one class which is PersonModel.

Comment: You should look into using ViewModels. Convert your data to/from DataSets in the controller. Even better: stop using Datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need fill data of table to dataset using `sqlDa.Fill(dt, "Person");` and set to View by `return View(dt.Tables["Person"]);`

You can change your code to

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            DataSet dt = new DataSet();



            using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("ABC"))
            {
                sqlcon.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Person", sqlcon);
                sqlDa.Fill(dt, "Person");
            }

            return View(dt.Tables["Person"]);
        }
```

And change your cshtml to

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
          {
             <th>@col.Caption</th>
          }
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
    {
       <tr>
          @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
          {
             <td>@cell.ToString()</td>
          }
       </tr>
    }      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this line  sqlDa.Fill(dt, "Person"); gives error  "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Data.DataSet'  "   and this line   dt.Tables["Person"]  gives  this error message "DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'Tables' and no accessible extension method 'Tables' accepting a first argument of type 'DataTable' could be found"

Comment: Did you change to DataSet dt = new DataSet(); ?

Comment: Yes, I changed it know.There is no build error but I am getting same meaningless output again "System.Data.DataRowCollection [i][1]"

Comment: Thanks it worked! The reason of meaningless output is just cshtml or both of them?

Comment: both of controller and cshtml have issue, if issue was resolve, you can mark answer as accepted thanks